# Pointers and Arrays [ pointers to int vs pointers to char]

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

**Why do pointers behave differently when they are pointing to an integer array and a character array?**

For example

```
int num[] = {1,2,3};
cout << num ;
```

*This prints out the **ADDRESS** of the first element*

```
char list[] = { '1', '2', '3'};
cout << list ;
```

*This prints out the **VALUE** of entire elements of array!*

Likewise

```
cout << (num+1) ;
```

prints out the ADDRESS of the second element. While

```
cout << (list+1);
```

prints out the VALUE of entire array beginning from the second element

From my understanding, array name is a pointer to the first element of the array. Without the dereference operator(*), the pointer should return the address of the element. But why is the char pointer returning the value?

Comment: The different is that `operator<<` is an overloaded function, and there is a different overload for `char *` than for other pointer types

Comment: C is not C++ is not C. Don't spam tags!

Comment: I didn't realize this problem was specifically for C++. I thought this was related to the Pointers & array concept as a whole. Sorry

Answer (score 5):

It is not pointers behaving differently: the behavior is how C++ standard library handles pointer output.

Specifically, operator `<<` has a [non-member overload for `const char *`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2), which handles null-terminated C strings. This is the overload applied to printing `char` array. Note that your character array is *not* null-terminated, so printing it produces undefined behavior. You can fix this by adding zero to the array of characters:

```
char list[] = { '1', '2', '3', '\0'};
```

There is also [an overload that takes `void *`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt), which applies to printing an `int` pointer.

Comment: You can just use `0` instead of`'\0`.